# Function to find the (5) highest value of a column and merge together with lowest value according different value of other columns

Tags: r, list, function, loops

I would like to use a function to do this following task easier: find 5 highest value of a certain value in a column by grouping according different columns value and as well keep the lower value of this first column under another name, and merge  all together. Read my script below for first understanding.

I have a table with 5 columns:
Taxa, Year, Station, Species, and Biomass.
I have 4 types of taxa (diatoms, dinoflagellates, flagellates and ciliates), Two years: 2018and 2019, different stations for each years (2018: P1,P2,P3,P4,P5, PICE1, SICE3, And 2019: P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,Sice4), different species (which are different between the Taxa) and their respective biomass value.

I would like to create a data frame: in which I get the 5 most high value of biomass for each species of each taxa, at each year, at each stations. And the rest of the species, I would like to change their names for “Others_#” with # corresponding to their respective taxa (ex: “others_diatoms).

For that I have done a lot of steps but I am sure there is another way to do it.

For instance for the diatoms how I did it is :

```
  #subset only year 2018, station P1, with decreasing order of the shallowdepth column
P1_18 <- data %>% 
    subset(Taxa == "Diatoms" & Year == "2018" & Station=="P1") %>% 
    arrange(desc(Biomass))
  
  #Keep top 5 value
  top5_P1_18 <- P1_18 %>%
    head(5) 
  
  #keep the rest
  Otherdiatoms_P1_18 <-
    P1_18[-c(1:5),]  #remove the first 5 highest biomass value for each species‘’’
#For P2 in 2018
P2_18 <- data %>% 
  subset(Year== " 2018" & Station=="P2") %>% 
  arrange(desc(Biomass)) 

top5_P2_18 <- P2_18 %>%
  head(5) 

Otherdiatoms_P2_18 <-
  P2_18[-c(1:5),]
```

Etc for each stations at each year and for as well the 3 others taxa.

At the end :

```
#merge top5 tables
top5_diatoms <- bind_rows(top5_P1_19,top5_P2_19,top5_P3_19,top5_P4_19,top5_P5_19,top5_P6_19,top5_P7_19,top5_Sice4_19,
                     top5_P1_18,top5_P2_18,top5_P3_18,top5_P4_18,top5_P5_18,top5_PICE1_18,top5_SICE3_18)

#merge the other diatoms
Others_diatoms<- bind_rows(Otherdiatoms_P1_19,Otherdiatoms_P2_19,Otherdiatoms_P3_19,Otherdiatoms_P4_19,Otherdiatoms_P5_19,Otherdiatoms_P6_19,Otherdiatoms_P7_19,Otherdiatoms_Sice4_19,
                 Otherdiatoms_P1_18,Otherdiatoms_P2_18,Otherdiatoms_P3_18,Otherdiatoms_P4_18,Otherdiatoms_P5_18,Otherdiatoms_PICE1_18,Otherdiatoms_SICE3_18)
#NameSize: change all name species by "Other diatoms"
Others_diatoms$Species <- "Other diatoms"

#combine both together
diatoms_toplot<- bind_rows(top5_diatoms, Others_diatoms)

and then #combine the 4 tables taxa (

Final_merge<-bind_rows(diatoms_toplot, dinoflagellates_toplot,flagellates_toplot,ciliates_toplot)
```

I was thinking of creating sort of list for the several columns of the data frames and apply a function on each... but I am a bit lost so if any help on that, even for small steps I would be happy :)

Example of short part of my data:  `dput(data) structure(list(Taxa = c("Diatoms", "Diatoms", "Diatoms", "Diatoms",  "Diatoms", "Diatoms", "Diatoms", "Diatoms", "Diatoms", "Diatoms",  "Diatoms", "Diatoms", "Diatoms", "Diatoms", "Diatoms", "Diatoms",  "Diatoms", "Diatoms", "Diatoms", "Diatoms", "Diatoms", "Diatoms",  "Diatoms", "Diatoms", "Diatoms", "Diatoms", "Diatoms", "Diatoms",  "Diatoms", "Diatoms", "Diatoms", "Diatoms", "Diatoms", "Diatoms",  "Flagellates", "Flagellates", "Flagellates", "Flagellates", "Flagellates",  "Flagellates", "Flagellates", "Flagellates", "Flagellates", "Flagellates",  "Ciliates", "Ciliates", "Ciliates", "Ciliates", "Ciliates", "Ciliates",  "Ciliates", "Ciliates", "Ciliates", "Ciliates", "Ciliates", "Ciliates",  "Ciliates", "Ciliates", "Ciliates", "Ciliates", "Ciliates", "Ciliates",  "Ciliates", "Ciliates", "Ciliates", "Ciliates", "Ciliates", "Ciliates",  "Ciliates", "Ciliates", "Ciliates", "Ciliates", "Ciliates", "Ciliates",  "Ciliates", "Ciliates", "Ciliates", "Ciliates", "Ciliates", "Ciliates",  "Ciliates", "Ciliates", "Ciliates", "Ciliates", "Ciliates", "Ciliates",  "Ciliates", "Ciliates", "Ciliates", "Flagellates", "Flagellates",  "Flagellates", "Flagellates", "Flagellates", "Flagellates", "Flagellates",  "Flagellates", "Flagellates", "Flagellates", "Flagellates", "Flagellates",  "Flagellates", "Flagellates", "Dinoflagellates", "Dinoflagellates",  "Dinoflagellates", "Dinoflagellates", "Dinoflagellates", "Dinoflagellates",  "Dinoflagellates", "Dinoflagellates", "Dinoflagellates", "Dinoflagellates",  "Dinoflagellates", "Dinoflagellates", "Dinoflagellates", "Dinoflagellates" ), Year = c(2018, 2019, 2019, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019,  2018, 2019, 2018, 2019, 2018, 2019, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2018, 2018,  2019, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2018, 2019,  2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019,  2019, 2019, 2019, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2018, 2019, 2018, 2019,  2018, 2019, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2018, 2019, 2018,  2019, 2018, 2019, 2018, 2019, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2018, 2018,  2019, 2018, 2019, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2018, 2019, 2018, 2019,  2018, 2019, 2019, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019,  2018, 2019, 2018, 2019, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019,  2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2018), Station = c("P3",  "P6", "P7", "PICE1", "SICE3", "P4", "P5", "P6", "P7", "SICE3",  "Sice4", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P3", "P5", "P6", "P7", "PICE1", "SICE3",  "Sice4", "SICE3", "P4", "P7", "PICE1", "SICE3", "Sice4", "P5",  "P7", "PICE1", "Sice4", "P4", "P5", "P7", "P3", "P4", "P6", "P1",  "P2", "P3", "P5", "P7", "Sice4", "P1", "Sice4", "P3", "P1", "P2",  "P2", "P5", "P7", "PICE1", "Sice4", "P2", "P2", "P3", "P3", "P5",  "P6", "P7", "Sice4", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P3", "P3", "P4",  "P4", "P5", "SICE3", "P1", "P2", "PICE1", "SICE3", "Sice4", "P1",  "Sice4", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P3", "P3", "P4", "P4", "P5",  "P5", "P6", "P3", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P6", "P7", "Sice4", "P1",  "P2", "P2", "P3", "P3", "P4", "P4", "P2", "P3", "P3", "P4", "Sice4",  "P2", "P2", "P5", "P6", "P7", "PICE1", "SICE3", "Sice4", "SICE3" ), Species = c("Chaetoceros hibiscus", "Chaetoceros hibiscus",  "Chaetoceros hibiscus", "Chaetoceros hibiscus", "Chaetoceros hibiscus",  "Chaetoceros australis", "Chaetoceros australis", "Chaetoceros australis",  "Chaetoceros australis", "Chaetoceros australis", "Chaetoceros australis",  "Cylindrotheca", "Cylindrotheca", "Cylindrotheca", "Cylindrotheca",  "Cylindrotheca", "Cylindrotheca", "Cylindrotheca", "Cylindrotheca",  "Cylindrotheca", "Cylindrotheca", "Entomoneis", "Eucampia", "Eucampia",  "Eucampia", "Eucampia", "Eucampia", "Fragilariopsis", "Fragilariopsis",  "Fragilariopsis", "Fragilariopsis", "Fragilariopsis nana", "Fragilariopsis nana",  "Fragilariopsis nana", "Bicosta spinifera", "Bicosta spinifera",  "Bicosta spinifera", "Pathronus", "Pathronus", "Pathronus", "Pathronus",  "Pathronus", "Pathronus", "Plusimus", "Mesodinium", "Scuticociliatia",  "Braconus", "Braconus", "Braconus", "Braconus", "Braconus", "Braconus",  "Braconus", "Acanthostomella", "Acanthostomella", "Acanthostomella",  "Acanthostomella", "Acanthostomella", "Acanthostomella", "Acanthostomella",  "Acanthostomella", "Liboa", "Liboa", "Liboa", "Liboa", "Liboa",  "Liboa", "Liboa", "Liboa", "Liboa", "Liboa", "Leegaardiella ovalis",  "Leegaardiella ovalis", "Leegaardiella ovalis", "Leegaardiella ovalis",  "Leegaardiella ovalis", "Leegaardiella sol", "Leegaardiella sol",  "Leprotintinnus", "Lohmannio", "Lohmannio", "Lohmannio", "Lohmannio",  "Lohmannio", "Lohmannio", "Lohmannio", "Lohmannio", "Lohmannio",  "Lohmannio", "Chrysophyceae", "Chrysophyceae", "Chrysophyceae",  "Chrysophyceae", "Chrysophyceae", "Chrysophyceae", "Chrysophyceae",  "Dinobryonus", "Dinobryonus", "Dinobryonus", "Dinobryonus", "Dinobryonus",  "Dinobryonus", "Dinobryonus", "Amphidus", "Amphidus", "Amphidus",  "Amphidus", "Amphidus", "Amphidipoma", "Amphidipoma", "Amphidipoma",  "Amphidipoma", "Amphidipoma", "Amphidipoma", "Amphidipoma", "Amphidipoma",  "Amphidoma acuminata"), Biomass = c(2.5722570760978, 106.489043401096,  11.3660482634744, 23.6180471200604, 4.09736836295174, 2.77106585864742,  12.223960073548, 72.7319818648167, 8.1427752718168, 3.58881675476654,  101.787835667047, 9.47093811201888, 0.14002298927298, 0.0767060109516124,  0.0373241446028316, 0.169776162765161, 1.08282241487347, 0.195956004017996,  0.574227994044988, 1.30410474481671, 0.362778732033109, 5.11147483254336,  7.67526064939454, 11.1631040712476, 31.3527468551935, 58.6443407164168,  90.2661658419651, 0.0446244917247616, 0.840336011374516, 0.652638825938322,  1.60247037093698, 1.89950606550275, 13.9012274189626, 1.03046243784118,  0.966327867145711, 0.316060682764314, 0.165776507451685, 0.58830523425,  28.166516349, 9.36453636, 1.019766267, 0.9057995505, 2.6816984875,  0.144669507, 29.201684359, 46.8677637926364, 13.6932074914416,  24.4990583557351, 1.74088105245273, 3.57267406669825, 0.399665183658365,  18.7494388294602, 1.65382368830652, 1.68834080413432, 1.67395923,  1.7191065981177, 0.25746012, 3.42252693, 10.46782755, 12.63325329,  27.28561977, 44.3880970044607, 9.62682960654306, 54.4142437051378,  26.354896524942, 41.6469905251234, 31.7857807556355, 18.7536292316292,  10.7666063235056, 48.0379878500564, 9.08744172316435, 22.7274163346186,  3.65192443308688, 2.04894292586637, 2.25383716895731, 12.0194344079741,  447.459734842254, 46.5926400106843, 6.37144904526355, 4.60879900929901,  5.52746175351058, 0.763267538, 4.75285289064043, 0.167946768,  1.00104490733456, 0.376861628, 32.4558052933942, 1.661617478,  3.61765976, 37.45879402342, 63.7914816, 12.4429536, 73.16948865,  2.2097162, 8.4491484, 0.87203655, 5.56556268491627, 0.042503908636136,  12.8078492514965, 0.370958637607761, 0.970623318853854, 0.251205938893951,  2.95334285993973, 1.1088252, 1.16333569359, 0.697977, 0.2501982,  8.119062, 1.0277386590735, 0.26885925, 0.3437478, 11.4169177,  0.0743094, 0.5457011783256, 0.36260916888235, 1.62785205, 0.0876508754603 )), row.names = c(NA, -117L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame" ))`

Comment: Is there two datasets i.e. `data` and `depthint_biomass_5sp_diatoms`

Comment: Is only 1 data set, name of "data", mistake will adding the example...

Comment: ok, can you please update your post.  Because of several subset, it is a bit confusing

Answer (score 0):

We could use `slice_head` after grouping by

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
   arrange(Taxa, Year, Station, desc(Biomass)) %>%
   group_by(Taxa, Year, Station) %>%
   slice_head(n = 5)
```

Or with `slice_max`

```
data %>%
    group_by(Taxa, Year, Station) %>%
    slice_max(n = 5, order_by = Biomass)
```

---

If we need to change the names of the 'Taxa' with a prefix 'Others' for those that are not the top 5

```
library(stringr)
df1 <- data %>%
  arrange(Taxa, Year, Station, desc(Biomass)) %>%
  group_by(Taxa, Year, Station) %>%
  slice_head(n = 5) 
nm1 <- unique(df1$Taxa)
data <- data %>%
    mutate(Taxa = case_when(! Taxa %in% nm1 ~ str_c('Other_', Taxa), TRUE ~ Taxa))
```

Then, we `filter` the ones that are having 'Other' along with the 'df1' already created

```
data %>%
     filter(str_detect(Taxa, '^Other_')) %>%
     bind_rows(df1 %>% ungroup)
```

Comment: OK thanks a lot. Is it possible to create a df but instead of keeping the 5 first , removing the five first? I tried :  data %>% 
   arrange(Taxa, Year, Station, desc(Biomass)) %>%
   group_by(Taxa, Year, Station) %>%
    slice((6:length(data1)))                    or the others idea is to rsubstract the rows saved (from the head = 5 function) from the original table (as they are in duplicate) as :  df1 <- data %>%
  arrange(Taxa, Year, Station, desc(Biomass)) %>%
  group_by(Taxa, Year, Station) %>%
  slice_head(n = 5)   and data - df1

Comment: Problem solved: #keep the 5 highest biomass
data_head5 <- data %>%
  arrange(Taxa, Year, Station, desc(Biomass)) %>%
  group_by(Taxa, Year, Station) %>%
  slice_head(n = 5)

#get df without the row of data1
data_without5head <- anti_join(data, data_head5)


#Add value of column taxa into colum "Species"
data_without5head$Species <-  data_without5head$Taxa

#add Others_
data_without5head$Species <- str_c('Other ', data_without5head$Species)

#merge the two tables
data_head5_others<- bind_rows(data_head5,data_without5head)